# Preventing postback when form is invalid in webforms

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, validation, webforms

I've made a form and added form validation. This I'm doing by using this code of my input field in my ascx code file:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="FirstName">
        <asp:Localize ID="Localize5" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="fieldText" />
    </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="myTextField" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
</div>
```

And in the code behind I do this when `Me.Load` is fired:

```vb
myTextField.Attributes.Add("required", "required")
```

The problem happens when I click on the submit button:

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" id="btnSumbit">
    <asp:Localize ID="Localize24" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="submitText" />
</button>
```

Code behind

```vb
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSumbit.ServerClick
    Response.Redirect("https://stackoverflow.com")
End Sub
```

This event prevents the form validation in the browser. Because it's doing a postback. This is the rendered HTML:

```html
<button onclick="__doPostBack('ctl53$btnSumbit','')" id="ctl53_btnSumbit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    Submit
</button>
```

What can I do only use a postback when the form is valid?

Comment: why not use asp.net built-in validation controls? RequiredFieldValidator will do the job for you, and tie-in with ASP.NET's standard postback method. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx

Comment: @ADyson: what you're saying is true. But I'm coming from MVC and C# and that's the way I do it there.

Comment: MVC also has its own validation framework based on data attributes on the model properties, don't you use that either? Apart from anything else, your solution above is not robust because there's no server-side validation, and client-side validation is trivial to bypass for those who wish to do so.

Comment: @ADyson: Yes I use that but in webforms it's impossible to do that. But I add also the `required` and `pattern` attributes.

Comment: Yeah as far as I know you can't, totally different structure to everything. The built-in way in WebForms is using the validator controls I linked to above. They provide automatic server- and client-side validation of the control they are applied to.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code inside a script tag or file

```js
var originalDoPostback = __doPostBack;
__doPostBack = function (p1, p2) {

    if (document.querySelectorAll('input:invalid').length === 0) {
        originalDoPostback(p1, p2);
    }
};
```

This will change `__doPostBack` to your `function(p1, p2) { /* code stuff */ }`. When there are no invalid input fields do the original postback _(named `originalDoPostback`), else do nothing.